# MongoDb - Sort by highest-value element of array field

Tags: arrays, mongodb, sorting, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with documents like follows and I want to sort the documents with respect to the highest `date` value they contain in `status` array:

```
[{
  "_id": "1",
  "name": "Tea",
  "status": [
    {
      "state": "a",
      "date": "2019-08-22"
    },
    {
      "state": "b",
      "date": "2019-07-12"
    },
  ],
  "_id": "2",
  "name": "Coffee",
  "status": [
    {
      "state": "c",
      "date": "2019-05-01"
    },
    {
      "state": "b",
      "date": "2019-12-31"
    }
  ]
}]
```

So, in the example, the values to be used for sorting should be like:

- *Tea*: highest status date `2019-08-22` *(state: a)*
- *Coffee*: highest status date `2019-12-31` *(state: b)*

Any ideas?

Comment: I fail to see the usefulness of an array here. Create flat documents with an index on name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get sorted element with repect to max date inside the array, you need to extract the maximum date from the array which you can easily do with the [**`$max`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) operator.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "sortDate": { "$max": "$status.date" }
  }},
  { "$sort": { "sortDate": 1 }}
])
```

Comment: This provides both ascending/descending sort based on max value.

Comment: If you want the order in descending order with the max date then Alex answer will work for you. Else you can go with this.

Answer (score 6):

```
db.collection.find().sort({"status.date":-1})
```

From the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-type-comparison-order/#arrays):

> With arrays, a less-than comparison or **an ascending sort compares the smallest element of arrays**, and a greater-than comparison or **a descending sort compares the largest element of the arrays**.